# I can't access my wireless connection

Tags: wireless

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and for some reason, out of the blue, my computer won't connect to my wifi signal, but ethernet works fine. It won't even allow me the option to connect to wifi. I've been trying for months, what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but I had the same problem when I first installed ubuntu. You should restart and go into boot options at startup and disable "Secure Boot". Then restart and see if it helps.